# Attempting to open a dll whenever logging on to server after SQL Server upgrade to 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2003, sql-server, sql-server-2008

The environment is Windows Server 2003 SP2 32-bit, SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1

When logging on to the server the following message box is displayed 'you are attempting to open a file of type 'application extension' (.dll)'.  If selected, the module is sqdedev.dll (SQL Setup Enumerator API).

This server was just converted from SQL Server 2000 SP4.  The conversion took place without a hitch.  The hot fix KB942288-v4 was applied to the server for the installer without a flaw and the upgrade ran rather quickly and the results were exactly as expected  with the exception of this message.

Was there a flaw in the conversion or is there a way to fix this?  This is a test server so it is not critical but I do not have a snapshot to roll back to.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like there's something from the legacy SQL 2000 install set in a startup folder or in the registry somewhere.

If it's specific to one user, look in that user's Startup folder in the start menu or in the registry key `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`.

If it's all users, then look in the All Users start folder or `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`

Comment: Could you walk me through the keys?  Help me with what you mean by Current Version?

Comment: Do you mean HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50_MSSQLSERVER\MSSQLServer\CurrentVersion?

Comment: No, not the SQL key.  The ones I mentioned are designated as startup items.  Values in those keys (the Run keys) are pointers to items that get run when a user logs into the system.

Comment: ok, I googled and looked under under HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run.  I don't see sqdedev.dll.

Comment: There is no HKLM\Software\Microsoft\CurrentVersion\Run

Comment: Sorry, my bad.  I missed part of the path.  I updated my answer with the correct paths.

Comment: no problem.  now what?  what do i look for?  nothing obvious is sticking out at me.